# Metro App Prevent BackgroundTask from Running if UI is Open

Tags: windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, c#-5.0, winrt-async

I have a `BackgroundTask` which connects to a remote server and does some kind of action, download, upload, etc. This task runs every 15 minutes.

The `UI` associated to the `BackgroundTask` does the same and more.

However, the remote server allows only one session per login and I have only one login to that server. As such, I need a strategy to ensure that either one of these two are active and not both.

Currently, I store a value in `LocalSettings` which indicates if the UI is open or not. If the UI is closed, the `BackgroundTask` will do it's job as per normal. If the `UI` is open, the `BackgroundTask` will do nothing.

This works fine, except for when the `BackgroundTask` is in the middle of it's Run and the UI is launched. I need a way of cancelling this `BackgroundTask` immediately when the UI is launched, so that the UI can use the login to the remote server. Any tips or suggestions on how this may be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Thanks to **Dave Smits** for the solution.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/032ac848-51f5-4cb1-be04-690da411261a)

In a nutshell:

- Register for `Cancellation` event in `Run` method.
- In the `Cancellation` event handler ensure connected sessions are disconnected.
- When the `OnLaunched` event is raised in the `App` object, `Unregister` the
  task which raises the task `Cancellation` event.